# Joining record with the most recent record on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a SQL view. How could I select the most recent record from one table leaving others as is. I need to select all records from all tables, which works fine, but I need to select just the  most recent Proposal by date, which I'm having issue with.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    i.CustInqDate AS InquiryDate,
    i.CustomerID,
    prop.ProposalID,
    i.CustInqryID
FROM         
    ptsweb.tblCustomerInqry AS i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ptsweb.tblCustomer AS tc ON tc.CustomerID = i.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN
    ptsweb.tblProposal AS prop ON tc.CustomerID = prop.CustomerID 
                               AND prop.DateCreated = (SELECT MAX(ptsweb.tblProposal.DateCreated) 
                                                       FROM ptsweb.tblProposal)
WHERE     
    (i.CustInqDate > '1/1/2017') 
    AND tc.CustomerID = 101568
```

But it does not show any records. This customer has multiple inqueries and proposals. Some records has one record, one proposal, or it can be either way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `apply`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM ptsweb.tblCustomerInqry i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ptsweb.tblCustomer tc
     ON tc.CustomerID = i.CustomerID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) p.*
      FROM ptsweb.tblProposal p
      WHERE tc.CustomerID = p.CustomerID 
      ORDER BY p.DateCreated DESC
     ) p
WHERE i.CustInqDate > '2017-01-01' AND tc.CustomerID = 101568;
```

Comment: so now it selects by most recent Proposal by datecreated, right?

Comment: @Fresher . . . Yes, this is the logic that is implemented.